# Create a AppCompat Theme with a Custom ActionBar layout

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-appcompat

I have a problem. I created a theme in my styles.xml like this:

```
<resources>
  <style name="BluePixelsTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:height">75dp</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions"></item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Now in my MainActivity is set the layout of the ActionBar like this:

```
ActionBar.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.setup_nav_bar);
ActionBar.SetDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
((Toolbar)ActionBar.CustomView.Parent).SetContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
```

But this causes an error that ActionBar has a `null` value...
When I am not using a AppCompat theme it all works great, but how can I make this work **with** an AppCompat Theme?

Please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code.

```
 this.SupportActionBar.DisplayOptions = (int)ActionBarDisplayOptions.ShowCustom;
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        View view = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.setup_nav_bar,
        null);
        Android.Support.V7.App.ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new Android.Support.V7.App.ActionBar.LayoutParams(Android.Support.V7.App.ActionBar.LayoutParams.MatchParent, Android.Support.V7.App.ActionBar.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
        SupportActionBar.SetCustomView(view, layoutParams);

        Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar parentToolbar = view.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.ll_toolbar);
        parentToolbar.SetContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
```